# filtering a list for one absolute condition

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, filtering

I have a list of arrays called `x`

```
[array([ -1.5768,  10.843 ,   2.5462,  -2.9362,   0.    ]),
 array([-0.38214,  8.3909 ,  2.1624 , -3.7405 ,  0.     ]),
 array([-0.24811, -0.17797,  4.9068 ,  0.15429,  0.     ]),
 array([-0.96511,  9.4111 ,  1.7305 , -4.8629 ,  0.     ]),
 array([-1.6162 ,  0.80908,  8.1628 ,  0.60817,  0.     ])]
```

I want to check if the first column of each row is greater than >0.
([ -1.5768, -0.38214,..... )]

If ALL the rows match this condition I want to return a "yes"
else I want to return a "no".

I'm able to return a "yes" or "no" for each row (so the output will be many yeses or noes  but I just want the output to be one yes or no.

```
for row in x:
    if row[0] > 0:
        print ('yes')
    else: print('no')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In python you can use a generator expression within `all()` function:

```
In [7]: arr = [[ -1.5768,  10.843 ,   2.5462,  -2.9362,   0.    ],
   ...:  [-0.38214,  8.3909 ,  2.1624 , -3.7405 ,  0.     ],
   ...:  [-0.24811, -0.17797,  4.9068 ,  0.15429,  0.     ],
   ...:  [-0.96511,  9.4111 ,  1.7305 , -4.8629 ,  0.     ],
   ...:  [-1.6162 ,  0.80908,  8.1628 ,  0.60817,  0.     ]]

In [8]: 

In [8]: all(i[0] > 0 for i in arr)
Out[8]: False

In [9]: all(i[0] < 0 for i in arr)
Out[9]: True
```

In numpy you can do it just with a simple comparison and `array.all()` attribute:

```
In [11]: import numpy as np

In [12]: arr = np.array(arr)

In [14]: (arr[:, 0] > 0).all()
Out[14]: False

In [15]: (arr[:, 0] < 0).all()
Out[15]: True
```